# |error: expected ')' before ';' token| Declaration of variables doubts

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a problem whit my code, because he keeps showing me that error: `expected ')' before ';' token|`, in the rows inside the `for`. I think I'm not declaring this correctly for C++.

```
int main(void) {


    float Z = 1.0;
    float R = 1.0;
    float ks = 1.0;
    float ke = 1.0;
    float kw = 1.0;
    int nr = 5.0;
    int nz = 5.0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int a;
    float vetorq = 1;
    float kn = 1;

    float T[nr][nz] = {0};


    for (a = 0; a < 100; a++){


    for (i = 0; i < nz; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < nr; j++){


            float an = (i + (1 / 2)) * ((pow(R, 2))*nz*kn/ ((pow(nr, 2))* Z);
            float ae = (i + 2) * Z * ke / nz;
            float aw = ((i+1) * kw * Z) / nz;
            float asul = (i + (1 / 2)) * (pow(R, 2))*nz*ks / (Z * (pow(nr, 2));
            float ap = an + ae + aw + asul;
            float aef = 0;
```

Comment: The error message is literally telling you what's wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: BTW, there is something wrong with this statement: `int nr = 5.0;`.  The `5.0`, is not an integer, but a floating point.  You are asking the compiler to convert floating point to integer.  Much easier if you used `const nr = 5;`.

Comment: Multiplying a value with itself is more efficient than `pow(x, 2)`.  For example, `R * R` is more efficient than `pow(R, 2)`.

Comment: Beware the integer division.  In *integer* division, `1/2==0`.  However, `1.0 / 2.0 == 0.5`.  The `.0` makes the numbers floating point instead of integer.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to prove to us that the compiler is wrong? Work backwards from the point of the error, and show that you do not encounter an open parenthesis without first encountering the corresponding close parenthesis. (Keep a running total. Count up one when you encounter a close parenthesis and down one for an open parenthesis. You prove your point by never going negative.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully check the expression 
`float an = (i + (1 / 2)) * ((pow(R, 2))*nz*kn/ ((pow(nr, 2))* Z);`
It seems that you opened more round parentheses than closed. Probably you forgot one closing parenthesis somewhere...

Comment: `float asul = (i + (1 / 2)) * (pow(R, 2))*nz*ks / (Z * (pow(nr, 2)); ` is also missing a close parenthesis.

Comment: Right. In any case I guess once understood the first error, he will understand all of them...